# Nested view crashes when trying to update EnvironmentObject value

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, preview, environmentobject

I want to hide and unhide the tab bar in the root view of my app using other views. I have used environment object for it, however when i try to update the value of environment object the preview crashes.

here is a step by step; i have a class that conforms to the ObservableObject class that has one property, isPresent.

```
final class TabBarPresenter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPresent: Bool = true
    
    func updatePresentState() {
        isPresent.toggle()
    }
}
```

In the root view where i swap some views using the tab bar, i have declared the TabBarPresenter:

```
struct RootView: View {
    
    @State var selectedTab: Int = 0
    @StateObject var tabBarPresenter = TabBarPresenter()
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                HomeView()
                    .tag(0)
                
                //unrelated code...
            }
            
            //unrelated code...
        }
        .environmentObject(tabBarPresenter)
    }
}
```

and have passed down the object using the environmentObject modifier.

in another view where I show some details, I want to hide the tab bar so this is what I did:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = DetailsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {}
        .onAppear { viewModel.tabBarPresenter.updatePresentState() }
        .toolbar(.hidden)
    }

}

struct DetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailsView()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            .environmentObject(TabBarPresenter())
    }
}
```

i try to change the isPresent value when the view appears, but the preview crashes, furthermore, here is the code for DetailsViewModel:

```
final class DetailsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @EnvironmentObject var tabBarPresenter: TabBarPresenter
}
```

and finally, i call the DetailsView inside the HomeView (which itself is in the root view), here is the code for the HomeView:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {...}
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.presentDetailsView) {
                DetailsView()
            }
        }
        .toolbar(.hidden, for: .bottomBar)
        
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you are nesting `ObservableObjects`, such that `TabBarPresenter` is also declared inside
 `DetailsViewModel`. Note, there is **no relations** between your `tabBarPresenter` in your `RootView`
 and the one in your `DetailsView` (assuming it is nested).
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). and in particular
 show the code for `DetailsViewModel` and how you pass it around

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i updated the code to keep it minimal and gave extra info. Can you see the issue now?

Comment: `EnvironmentObject` only works inside a SwiftUI View

Comment: As mentioned, do not put `@EnvironmentObject` in a class, it is only for use in Views.
Also, **do not nest** ObservableObjects, it will give you troubles.
 Restructure your code to have only **one** source of truth in one ObservableObject class,
 and pass it around using, for example, `.environmentObject(...)` and
 `@EnvironmentObject var ...` in the child view.

Comment: Yes the problem is solved and it does not crash! but can you further elaborate on what you meant by not nesting ObservableObjects?

Comment: since you aren't using Combine you shouldn't have any ObservableObjects, use @State structs and bindings for your view data.

Comment: By nesting I mean when you have an ObservableObject declared/used inside another.
You have `TabBarPresenter` inside `DetailsViewModel`. Use one, eg:  `class DetailsViewModel: ObservableObject { @Published var isPresent: Bool = true }`
and pass it around the views. When `TabBarPresenter` becomes more complex, make it a 'struct' and the view will 
look after it through the wrapping ObservableObject automatically.
See the **official** way of managing your data here: [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Comment: oh ok got it, thanks for the help!